# How can you sort apps alphabetically in android jellybean 4.2.2?

Tags: android-versions, menu, tablet-apps

I use a Lenovo S600 tablet with Android Jellybean 4.2.2 OS,  the problem is that the apps are arranged randomly as I install them which leads to a lot of confusion.  I would like to arrange all the apps alphabetically so I know where to find the specific one I need. My previous tab had ICS OS which provided the option to arrange the iapps according to date or alphabet. But my current tab does not do so. How do I arrange them alphabetically?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From a Home screen, touch Apps.
2. Touch Menu ➔ View type.
3. Touch Alphabetical grid

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are describing the difficulties associated with the automatic introduction of shortcuts by Google play to the Home Screen. This is indeed dependent on the download order you personally control. The problem you are describing is common to new users of a tablet or smartphone, and indicates the need to become familiar with the techniques of 2 separate applications: Google Play, and the Launcher that controls your Home Screen. On the devices I'm familiar with, there is no automatic resorting function of shortcuts on Launcher screens.

Google Play is the easiest to control, by starting its app and exploring the Settings menu. You probably have enabled "Add icon to Home screen". As apps are downloaded by Google play, their shortcuts are added to the Home screen. As each fills the available space on the grid, additional screens are created to accept new ones. They are maintained in the order the apps are downloaded. You may turn off this setting, or, based on your new understanding, capitalize on this action. I personally have it disabled, and create shortcuts manually, leaving myself a tightly-controlled layout.

These shortcuts can be shifted, deleted, and added manually from the Launcher, which controls the Home Screen. Press and HOLD them and they will follow your drag movement to new spaces, or to the Trash icon to delete them, or carried to other screens by dragging them to the screen margins, and waiting for the screen to shift in until it becomes the active one. It will accept its new location when your finger is removed, indicating it is dropped as to your preference. Some experimentation is acceptable, and the techniques will strengthen within minutes. To add a new shortcut, while on the specific Launcher panel, open the App Drawer, which will open to your alphabetic list of apps. Press and HOLD, and possibly drag, the specific app to create a new shortcut at your desired location.

Find specifics to your device in this [User Guide](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideatab_s6000_ug/data/EN/chapter01.html). Chapter 1 clarifies the use of the Home Screen and Recent Apps.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer but I am not actually talking of the icons on the home screen/(desktop?)  I am asking about the main menu? (Sorry, I am unfamiliar with the technical terms) Where all the installed apps are displayed. Thanks again.

Comment: We  are actually taliking about the same things, and it is evident from the device's [User Guide](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideatab_s6000_ug/data/EN/chapter01.html). See the section about Home Screen and Recent apps in Chapter 1. It is a shame the manufacturers do not distribute effective documents with their devices, so that searching it out is your only option.

Comment: I am really sorry I may sound dumb, but I couldn't find an option to sort the apps in an alphabetical order in the app list even in the user guide in the link you provided. Thanks for all the trouble, mate!

Comment: One last try, and this is from my experience with a Samsung Galaxy Tab, which will have an App Drawer controlled differently than on a Lenova (assuming), but the technique may be the same. On my Galaxy Tab, when the App Drawer is open (Settings>View Type) presents "Alphabetical Grid" and "Customizable Grid". Mine is set Alphabetical. See if your Lenovo has a similar settings menu and choices.

Comment: Thanks, man for all the trouble. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Is it the  settings > Applications > Manage Applications > {Downloaded | All}  listing that you are speaking of.  If it is then click on the Menu button, and then choose "Sort Alphabetically" switching from the other way would bring up "Sort by size".  The view shows the application name and the size, but it does not show a date.

Answer (score 0):

I am using kitkat and found out that when you press and hold the blank space on the home screen you will see options then touch the 3 dots and under drawer settings and sort by choose title that way all your apps will be arranged alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Get to the applications screen, hit the menu button (mine is upper right with three dots), click on view type then hit alphabetical grid.  The customizable list allows you to move the icons around

Answer (score -1):

Please search "launcher" in the Google Play store. Pick one you like. Almost all of them do alphabetical sorting by default. Nova Launcher, Apex Launcher, SmartLauncher are some examples of what you will find when you search on google play store. What a launcher does is basically it changes visual layout of your icons and widgets. If you don't like a particular launcher, you could easily revert to previous or original layout simply by uninstalling it.